# How to count for a certain amount of seconds before breaking from program

Tags: python, time, pygame

```
if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(ship,missile) == True:
    ship.image = pygame.image.load("lose.jpg")
    ship.image = ship.image.convert()
    ship.rect = ship.image.get_rect()
    break
```

How do I make it so there is a few second wait while it shows 'lose.jpg' and then breaks and exits the program?

Comment: @Wooble This is different, since it deals with a application that needs to constantly process player input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def pause(time_to_wait):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    total = 0
    while True:
    total += clock.tick()
    if(total > time_to_wait):
        return
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: @user2045015 you mean this function? Or where to put the call `pause(1000)`?

Comment: the code you gave me where would i put that

Comment: @user2045015 at the beginning of your script